# Can Flash Media Server stream H264 over RTMP?

Tags: h.264, rtmp, flash-media-server

We use Flash Media Server to stream FLV videos over RTMP for security, seeking and adaptive bitrate capability.

We would like to move to H264 encoded videos in an MP4 container but this does not seem to work over RTMP.

Does FMS definitely support mp4 H264 over RTMP? Is FMS v4 required (we're on v3)?

Comment: 'Security'?  Good luck with that.

Comment: Yes. http://www.adobe.com/products/flash-media-encoder/features.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does.
Try using the Flash Media Encoder and you'll find options to stream using the H264 codec via RTMP.
Hope that helps.